# colors on android studio are different from color from the physical device

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

im creating an app and i changed the color of editext to #AE0202 and it looks great on the android studio but when i run the app on my physical device the color changes and is like orange instead of red my phone has android 11 cant figure out a solution (if i run the app on the emulator the colors are correct)